# getting max or min date in sql based on value of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with sql query:

I have a table with following values 4 columns:

```
Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Dept_Id, Join_Date, Salary
1, John, A, 20170101, 50000
2, David, B, 20160201, 60000
1, John, A, 20170606, 60000
```

If the employee belongs to department 'A' what is the latest salary and if employee is in Dept B what is the earliest salary.

Tried doing something else like this but doesn't work returns duplicates in case employee is in more than 1 dept

```
select salary,emp_id,join_date from employee
where emp_id in (select emp_id from employee where dept = 'A') 
group by emp_id 
having join_date = max(join_date)
union
select salary,emp_id,join_date from employee
where emp_id in (select emp_id from employee where dept != 'A') 
group by emp_id 
having join_date = min(join_date)
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: These examination questions are getting stranger and stranger. Just sayin'.  I suppose it shows how successful SO is: there's a kind of arms race between this community and the profs trying to come up with cut'n'paste-proof questions.

Comment: the column names in your statement are different than in your table
what does 'the latest salary' mean? do you refer to the salary of the person who joined latest?
"dpt != 'A'" might work in your case, but use "dept = 'B'" if you want to have restults just from rows with department = B

please put some more efford in your problems, before posting them on SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Salary, Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Dept_Id, Join_Date
  FROM employee
 WHERE Dept_Id   = 'A'
   AND Join_Date = ( SELECT MAX(Join_Date)
                       FROM employee
                      WHERE Dept_Id   = 'A'
                   )
UNION ALL
SELECT Salary, Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Dept_Id, Join_Date
  FROM employee
 WHERE Dept_Id   = 'B'
   AND Join_Date = ( SELECT MIN(Join_Date)
                       FROM employee
                      WHERE Dept_Id   = 'B'
                   )
```